# How do I remove a menu item on the fly?

Tags: java, android

My Android app has a navigation drawer with a menu.  In the free version of the app, I want to have a menu item to allow the user to Upgrade to the paid version.  Obviously I don't want this in the paid version.

How do I hide the menu item in the paid version?

The menu looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/btn_home"
        android:title="@string/nav_home"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_acc_upgrade"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black"
        android:title="@string/str_acc_upgrade" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_black"
        android:title="@string/nav_help"
        />
</menu>
```

In the activity, I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);

    if(isPaid()) {
        MenuItem upgrade = menu.findItem(R.id.action_acc_upgrade);
        upgrade.setVisible(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

If I run this through the debugger, it reaches the line `if(isPaid())` and then evaluates it as true, so goes into the setVisible part. The item still shows up in the menu, though.

I also tried removing the item from the menu instead of hiding it; the debugger shows that the item is removed, but then it still shows up when the menu is displayed.

How can I hide/remove this item?

### Edit

I'm using a navigation drawer to hold the menu. This is set up in onCreate as follows:

```
// Set up toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

// Set up navigation drawer
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.nav_drawer_open, R.string.nav_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

I suspect that this somehow bypasses onPrepareOptionsMenu etc? Is there a way of adding a listener which is called when the "open navigation drawer" button is clicked?  I can only find callbacks for the drawer being opened or closed, and they're called after the drawer has moved - I need to call them before.

Comment: Your code does work.

Comment: Did you try `Menu.removeItem()`?

Comment: Really, forpas?  It doesn't for me :(

Comment: Yes, Jeffrey, but it didn't seem to do anything.  I could see in the debugger that the item had been removed, but it still showed up when the menu was displayed.

Comment: @Sharon are you serious? You were talking about navigation drawer and you did not bother mention it?

Comment: So sorry - I hadn't really thought it through and didn't think it was relevant.  I guess because my code was finding the menu ok, I didn't think that the menu being in a drawer would affect things. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in `onCreate()` of your activity:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
navMenu.removeItem(R.id.action_acc_upgrade);
```

replace `nav_view` with your `NavigationView`'s id.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

1. The most convenient option: create 2 different productFlavours in your `build.gradle` file

   ```
   productFlavors {
       free {
         ...
       }
       paid {
         ...
       }
   }
   ```

   And then override your menu file without `action_acc_upgrade` item for paid flavour.
2. If you want change visibility programmatically, try to use `onPrepareOptionsMenu` instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
       if(isPaid()) {
           MenuItem upgrade = menu.findItem(R.id.action_acc_upgrade);
           upgrade.setEnabled(false);
           upgrade.setVisible(false);
       }
   }
   ```

   If you need to change your menu after creation, invoke `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: Thank you - that's helpful. I've gone for the second option this time, but I wondered how the first one works - how do I override the menu file for a particular flavour?  That's not one of the options when I create a layout file.

Comment: You can create different menu files with same name in the different packages. For example: free package: `src/free/res/menu/your_menu_file` and for paid: `src/paid/res/menu/your_menu_file`. You need to create these folders yourself. It works nicely

Comment: Or you can override menu file only for one flavor. And by default to do free.

Answer (score 1):

If it's *on the fly*, you need to override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and call `invalidateOptionsMenu` if applicable:

```
@Override public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_acc_upgrade).setVisible(!isPaid());
}
```

See [Activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)):

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is
>   called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can
>   use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise
>   dynamically modify the contents.

Comment: Thanks.  That link is helpful, I hadn't found that in the docs. I've added in onPrepareOptionsMenu as suggested above, but the menu item is still showing. If I set a breakpoint in onPrepareOptionsMenu, it only gets hit when the Activity initially starts, not when the menu is opened. Does this mean I'm somehow targeting the wrong menu?

Comment: I'm using a NavigationDrawer layout to handle this menu - is that relevant?  I've edited my original post to add details.

Comment: So it's the menu in NavigationDrawer? If you want to toggle menu item visibility in  NavigationDrawer, then it will not work for your case, but try @forpas solution.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` like this:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    if(isPaid()) {
       menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

**Notice:**
    Ensure get right value of isPaid() before `onPrepareOptionsMenu` callback, such as in `onCreate()` or `onResume()`.